# push in typescript of react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, types

I am studying typescript in react native.

If I typed the following code as vanilla javascript, the app works well.
But typed as a typescript, I received a message `circleStyles.push(styles.circleCorrect);` is an error. I understand it seems like the problem of type but I do not get how to solve it.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";

const screen = Dimensions.get("window");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  circle: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff4136",
    width: screen.width / 2,
    height: screen.width / 2,
    borderRadius: screen.width / 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  circleCorrect: {
    backgroundColor: "#28A125"
  },
  icon: {
    width: screen.width / 3
  }
});

export const Alert = ({ correct, visible }) => {
  if (!visible) return null;

  const icon = correct
    ? require("../assets/check.png")
    : require("../assets/close.png");

    const circleStyles = [styles.circle];

    if (correct) {
      **circleStyles.push(styles.circleCorrect);**
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={circleStyles}>
        <Image source={icon} style={styles.icon} resizeMode="contain" />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: But what error message do you get exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because TypeScript uses [inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) to implicitly determine types so `circleStyles` type is evaluated as an array of objects having the same fields than `styles.circle`.

You can declare `circleStyles` as an array of any kind of value.

```
const circleStyles: any[] = [styles.circle];
```

I would advice you however to type it more precisely by creating an [interface with optional fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) or using [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)....

Comment: Thanks! Error Stops. I would create an interface with optional fields according to your kind advice.